# kubernetes nginx virtual server subroute

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am abit confused on the kubernetes nginx virtual subroute. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#virtualserverroute-subroute

> "In the case of a prefix, the path must start with the same path as the path of the route of the VirtualServer that references this resource"

```
path: /coffee
action: 
    path: coffee
```

will the /coffee be passed to the app?

because when I try to deploy the virtualserver with the route it doesn't work (exmaple below)

```
path: /one
action: 
    path: hellok8s
```

however, this route that I am using previously is working

```
path: /
action: 
    path: hellok8s
```

So taking for example, if I have an app-1 and app-2... Should I differentiate them through the host or through a sub-path?

- app-1: helloworld.test.com
- app-2: helloworld2.test.com

or is there way that I can differentiate them through path like below?

- app-1: helloworld.test.com/appone
- app-2: helloworld.test.com/apptwo

--- edit

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: hellok8s-app-vs
spec:
  host: helloworld.moonshot.com
  tls:
    secret: nginx-tls-secret
    # basedOn: scheme
    redirect:
      enable: true
      code: 301
      upstream:
  - name: hellok8s
    service: hellok8s-service
    port: 8080
  routes:
  - path: /one
    action:
      proxy:
        upstream: hellok8s
        rewritePath: /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the path is the URL which will be exposed by the Nginx to world outside. What happens to that path internally depends on the action's sub attributes, some examples:

Here the `/coffee` is what end user sees but the request is sent to root of coffee service. So if the coffee would be a service in K8S running at 8080, the request will land at `coffee:8080`

```
path: /coffee
 action:
  pass: coffee
```

But there are more [actions](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#action). And let's say you use the [`action.proxy`](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#action-proxy) then you can define at a lot more granular level what should happen with path. So in below example, we are forwarding to the `coffee` service but the request path is being re-written to `filtercoffee`

```
proxy:
  upstream: coffee
  rewritePath: /filtercoffee
```

You can also use redirect, return in action's pass directive, but you must [use one of the four listed here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources/#action)

Comment: my bad I applied the wrong yaml file and i just tested the upstream it works. Can I check if I can access other namespace app with just [namespace]/[app]?

Comment: I think so, you can try! If you search for "tea-namespace/tea" - on same page, it says same thing.